# Excel doesn't calculate correctly except if hit enter in the data

Tags: excel, vba

What is happening is the following: I got some numerical data and put it into a Excel sheet. After, I used the function MAX().

```
|Line|  Function | Data|
|----|-----------|-----|
|  1 |=MAX(A1:A2)|  12 |
|  2 |           |  20 |
```

The result was 12.

After I selected the cell with 20, I clicked at the Formula bar and pressed enter. The calculation was made correctly.

Anyone know why this has happened?

Comment: Markdown is not working maybe

Comment: File > Options > Formulas > | Calculation Options - Manual?

Comment: Maybe at first cell which contains number 20 formatted as a string (you can notify the little triangle at the left upper corner of the cell) and after hitting enter it changed to number.

Comment: Calculation Options:Automatic, I've checked.

Comment: Strings: Yeah. Is there some way to do a bulk formatting?

Comment: I found it. Thanks a lot. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885